# Angular - why key.enter is not working inside mat-menu

Tags: angular, event-handling, enter, mat-input

I have the following input and I want to fire the event after pressing enter:

```
  <input
    matInput
    type="number"
    min="0"
    placeholder="0"
    (keyup.enter)="minValue($event)"
  />
```

I have also tried (keydown.enter)="minValue($event)" without success.
How can a user type a value and when pressing enter call the minValue method?

Also, when I am clicking on the input field to type a value the input box dissapears before write anything.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you check with the inspect element that the input is still there? maybe theres a css rule applying to it that it's making it really small or changin the display and it's causing the input to dissapear from the screen. Are you able to type after you click on it? any errors on the browser console?

Comment: @FlorenciaCames unfortunately, I still cannot type any value after clicking on the input field. No there are no errors on the browser console. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: And when you inspect the element with the developers tool with your browser, do you see if any css, styles are changing? or maybe the item is dissapearing from the DOM? do you have it inside any *ngIf or hidden div?

Comment: I see that I can type a value after clicking on the field when I include in the input element the click event as follows:     <input
      matInput
      type="number"
      min="0"
      placeholder="0"
      [(ngModel)]="inputValue"
      (click)="minValue($event)"
      (keydown.enter)="minValue($event)"
    /> 

Why does this happen?

Comment: @FlorenciaCames  minValue(event: any) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event);
  }

Comment: is `<input (keyup)="minValue($event)">` without the keyup.enter and the (click) working? Also if this input is inside a form, the form could be submitting with the hit of the enter. Can you try by placing the input outside any form and test if it's working in your app...

Comment: @FlorenciaCames You are right!! I have the input inside a mat-menu. If I place it outside the menu it works fine! So this is impossible if place it inside a mat-menu?

Comment: Probably the api and function for mat-menu are in conflict with this behaviour. <https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api> in that case the question should be reformulated with why key.enter is not working inside mat-menu. I haven't try this out but maybe beeing more specifict with this on the question can help you find the answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot.. your help was significant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

.html

```
<input
matInput
type="number"
min="0"
placeholder="0"
[(ngModel)]="myValue"
(keyup.enter)="minValue(myValue)"
/>
```

.ts

```
  minValue(evt){
    console.log(evt)
  }
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-material-inputs-eavg7d?file=app/form-field-appearance-example.html)**